# how to remove object from the JSON file?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, slice

I'm unable to remove random code generated from the JSON array object, `.splice` worked very fine for me while removing the whole line with all data. I have different tiers of codes, in this example I will need to remove just the random generated value from the "promoCodes" I will always receive this error:

`mycodes.slice(mycodes.indexOf(randomcode), 1)`

`TypeError: mycodes.indexOf is not a function`

.JSON

```
{
    "TIER1": {
        "rewardSize": 1,
        "probability": 0.8,
        "numberOfCodes": 2,
        "rewardSubtype": 1,
        "totalRewardSize": 2,
        "promoCodes": [
            "TEST1 - 1",
            "TEST1 - 2"
        ]
      },
      "TIER2": {
        "rewardSize": 3,
        "probability": 0.25,
        "numberOfCodes": 2,
        "rewardSubtype": 2,
        "totalRewardSize": 6,
        "promoCodes": [
            "TEST2 - 1",
            "TEST2 - 2"
        ]
      },
      "TIER3": {
        "rewardSize": 10,
        "probability": 0.15,
        "numberOfCodes": 2,
        "rewardSubtype": 3,
        "totalRewardSize": 20,
        "promoCodes": [
            "TEST3 - 1",
            "TEST3 - 2"
        ]
      },
      "TIER4": {
        "rewardSize": 25,
        "probability": 0.05,
        "numberOfCodes": 2,
        "rewardSubtype": 4,
        "totalRewardSize": 50,
        "promoCodes": [
            "TEST4 - 1",
            "TEST4 - 2"
        ]
      },
      "TIER5": {
        "rewardSize": 50,
        "probability": 0.04,
        "numberOfCodes": 2,
        "rewardSubtype": 5,
        "totalRewardSize": 100,
        "promoCodes": [
            "TEST5 - 1",
            "TEST5 - 2"
        ]
      },
      "TIER6": {
        "rewardSize": 100,
        "probability": 0.01,
        "numberOfCodes": 2,
        "rewardSubtype": 6,
        "totalRewardSize": 200,
        "promoCodes": [
            "TEST6 - 1",
            "TEST6 - 2"
        ]
      },
      "TIER7": {
        "rewardSize": 1000,
        "probability": 0.001,
        "numberOfCodes": 2,
        "totalRewardSize": 2000,
        "promoCodes": [
            "TEST7 - 1",
            "TEST7 - 2"
        ]
      }
    }
```

Code:

```
//fs setup
const fs = require('fs');
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/newtest.json', 'utf8');
let mycodes = JSON.parse(rawdata);
const TIER1 = mycodes['TIER1']['promoCodes'] 


//something above...
const randomcode = TIER1[Math.floor(Math.random() * TIER1.length)];
console.log(randomcode); //logs random generated code 
mycodes.slice(mycodes.indexOf(randomcode), 1)
fs.writeFileSync(__dirname + '/newtest.json', JSON.stringify(mycodes, 0, 4), 'utf8')
```

With `delete` I tried:
`delete [randomcode];`
`delete mycodes[randomcode];`
but nothing is being done in this case, as it never gets removed from the file.

Comment: So what to do when `delete` is also not working? I found that it should be used for objects, there are no errors, but it wouldn't be removed from the .JSON file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're trying to call the `slice` method on an `object` - the `mycodes` object - and this not gonna happen, because, the `slice` method is only defined for `String` or `Array` Standard built-in objects.

**One Solution**

```
const fs = require('fs');
let rawdata = fs.readFileSync(__dirname + '/newtest.json', 'utf8');
let mycodes = JSON.parse(rawdata);
const TIER1 = mycodes.TIER1.promoCodes;
const randomcode = TIER1[Math.floor(Math.random() * TIER1.length)];

// get the item from the TIER1 array that matches the randomcode
const foundItem = TIER1.find((item) => item === randomcode);

// remove that item from the TIER1 array
TIER1.splice(TIER1.indexOf(foundItem), 1);

// save the data again to the json file.
fs.writeFileSync(
    __dirname + '/newtest.json',
    JSON.stringify(mycodes, 0, 4),
    'utf-8'
);
```

Comment: Really interesting that this works, do you have idea how to make it work with `delete` instead? I'm curious, as `delete` should be working with the objects. Anyway thx much for this answer!

Comment: Actually, You cannot delete the random code from the `TIER1` object with `delete` operator since it works only with objects properties and the - for example - ` "TEST2 - 1"` item in the array is not a property, It's just an item in the array.

If you wanna - for example - remove the `promoCodes` property that holdes your promo codes from the TIER1 object you can do something like that:
`delete mycodes.TIER1.promoCodes;` this will remove the promoCodes array with delete operator, since it's a property inside the TIER1 object.